Was the idea of foxes with many tails invented in anime, or is it a Japanese folk religion thing?
In Anime, it is a recurring idea of the concept of a fox with many tails. Like in Naruto or in Tensei Shitara Slime Datta Ken.
Was this idea invented in Anime, or is it a Japanese folk religion thing?

I think the edition has a grammar mistake, though not completely sure

The nine-tailed fox is a mythical creature from Japanese Mythology. It's called Kyubi-no-Kitsune.

It's a Far Eastern thing.  There are the kitsune in Japan,  hồ ly tinh in Vietnam, huli jing in China, and kumiho in Korea.  Possibly others, but these will reveal a great deal of what you want to know
